# Algebra Confusion : tan functions and dividing by 0

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We know we can't divide both sides of an equation by a variable and then use this to cancel said variable unless we are certain that the variable is not 0. I was told that this is because we can't divide by 0. This made sense.
In comes the tan function. There were questions in which there were values which set tan (x) = inderminate ( cos x, the denominator, was 0) but my teacher said this is okay since 'the other side of the equation produced an inderminate result too'.

E.g. cot (2x) = 1/(1+tan(x)) ; for x=135 degrees, both are inderminate

My question is that if it's okay for both sides to be inderminate, why are we not allowed to divide both sides by a variable and cancel : when the variable is zero, both sides will again produce inderminate results. I think this maybe because when we use the variable division we then proceed to cancel pretending they aren't equal to zero. Is my idea correct? If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Please mention one equation containing setting $\tan x$ as infinite that your teacher mentioned as "okay". Giving examples helps others know more clearly what you are trying to say.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with something being $0$. There is something wrong in deducing results by cancelling such zeroes.

Comment: @John, so just the cancellation is where dividing by 0 goes wrong?

Comment: Well, not necessarily. All that you can say is that anything you get after such a step may be wrong or incomplete. E.g. if you have $x(x-1)=x$, cancelling $x$ is fine, to give $x=2$. **But** this isn't the only solution, another solution of the equation would be $x=0$. Therefore the method gave an incomplete answer. Another e.g. if you have $\cos x (\cos x -1)=\cos x$, then cancelling this gives $\cos x =2$ which can't be solved (in $\Bbb R$), so we may conclude there are no solutions to this equation. Really, the solution we wanted was $\cos x=0$. In this case the method gave a wrong answer.

Comment: The method the teacher uses for the instaneous moment of non-existence by the tangent function is  slick and glossy non-mathematics.  The points of non-existence need to be removed from the equation.

Comment: JohnDoe, got that. @William, how can do I do that in the equation in the question?

Comment: For all x /= 0, x/x = 1 or x/x = 1,  x /= 0. @Sal_99

Comment: In case you are wondering why I did not answer Math's question on my answer to your recent question about induction and well-ordering, it's because Math had trolled me and then pestered me daily for the past three weeks including using sockpuppets and lying to me. As I said to you, the PDF that Math linked you to is flawed, and you'll only understand if you work carefully through the real proof of equivalence over PA− that I described in my answer.